# excel - need a vba for: If len(worksheet.tab.name) <3 then change color to vbgreen end. thanks

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

Please assist. I need a code that would change colors of tabs based on length of text in that tab.

If len(worksheet.tab.name) <3 then change color to vbgreen end.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work:

```
Sub LittleGreenTab()
    Dim s As Worksheet, nm As String
    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        nm = s.Name
        If Len(nm) < 3 Then
            s.Tab.Color = 5287936
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the worksheet.name property:

```
if len(worksheet.name)<3 then worksheet.tab.color = RGB(0, 250, 0)
```